# Matplotlib >1 Line Style, Same Line, Different Colors per Line

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, linegraph

Given the following data frame and line graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
import numpy as np
fig, ax=plt.subplots(1)
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],
                'b':[2,3,4,5],
                'c':[3,4,5,6]})
colors=['r','g','b']
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', [colors]))
ax.plot(d[:3],'-ko',d[2:],'--ko')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You'll notice that I am trying to assign one color per line but it is not working. I also tried using the colors argument in ax.plot.
It seems like this should be straight forward.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: the `'k'` in `'-ko'` and `'--ko'` sets the color to black... maybe try removing that?

Comment: That makes sense, but if I do, I get ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "['r', 'g', 'b']"
could not convert string to float: 'r'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

1. the `'k'` in `'-ko'` and `'--ko'` sets the colour to black, so we need to remove that
2. `colors` is already a list, but you have put it inside square brackets again in the call to set_prop_cycle, and thus made it into a nested list: `[['r','g','b']]`. Remove the square brackets there and it all works fine: `ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', colors))`

So, your code will look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from cycler import cycler
import numpy as np
fig, ax=plt.subplots(1)
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],
                'b':[2,3,4,5],
                'c':[3,4,5,6]})
colors=['r','g','b']
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', colors))
ax.plot(d[:3],'-o',d[2:],'--o')
plt.show()
```

[image]